# Issue with GIL on Python 3.12.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-c-api, gil

I am using this code:

```
PyThreadState * thread = PyEval_SaveThread();
PyGILState_STATE gil = PyGILState_Ensure();

// ...

PyGILState_Release(gil);
PyEval_RestoreThread(thread);
```

In Python 3.11.8 it works well, but when I switched version to 3.12.2, my application is crashing on the first variable, error message is:

> Fatal Python error: the function must be called with the GIL held, after Python initialization and before Python finalization, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)

What is the problem and how can I fix? I know that some changes were introduced between 3.11 and 3.12 with GIL but I did not find any informations about issue that I have.

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++?

Comment: Tags changed. Do not use nonrelevant  tags as it is considered spam

Comment: Because my code is coming from Python C API

Answer (score 1):

You code makes no sense in any version of Python:

- `PyEval_SaveThread`/`PyEval_RestoreThread` are for releasing and reacquiring the GIL in a Python-launched (created by `threading` module) thread (though you'd normally use the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros to simplify this).
- `PyGILState_Ensure`/`PyGILState_Release` are to allow threads *not* launched by Python's `threading` module (and therefore lacking GIL state) to acquire the GIL prior to calling into Python level code.

Your error indicates you've either already released the GIL, or possible you're in a non-`threading`-created thread, and therefore `PyEval_SaveThread` can't be called (you're trying to save thread state that doesn't exist, because it's a not the active Python thread). You need to know which type of thread you are, and use *only* the GIL-management APIs associated with that type of thread (and definitely not release the GIL twice or the like).

I strongly suggest reading [the API docs for threading](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) to help understand the APIs you're calling.